# How to start embedded broker with ActiveMQ-CPP

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I'm using ActiveMQ-CPP in a project and want to start an embedded broker. I have found references to the 'MockBrokerService' but can't find documentation on it. What I have found says its for testing. Does ActiveMQ-CPP support launching of a fully functional embedded broker that can interact with other ActiveMQ instances for failover and so on?

Answer (score 3):

The C++ client is a client only, there is no C++ broker so no it cannot start an embedded broker.  Only the Java client can do that and only if you include the activemq-broker dependency and any other broker libs needed for your intended configuration.